# '3706': Provider cannot be found when trying to connect to SQL SERVER VIA VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server in Excel VIA VBA.

I am getting stuck with the Connection string, it doesn't want to open. I keep on getting the error - **Provider can not be found. It may not be properly installed.**

Here is my code to connect:

```
Option Explicit

Const SQLConStr As String = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=XXX\XXX;Database=XXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;"


Sub ConnectToDB()

    Dim PolicyDetails As ADODB.Connection
    Set PolicyDetails = New ADODB.Connection
    
    PolicyDetails.ConnectionString = SQLConStr 
    
    PolicyDetails.Open
    
    PolicyDetails.Close
    
    Set PolicyDetails = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have read a few of the previous questions regarding 32-bit/ 64- bit , but everything on my computer is run on 64-bit.

Does anyone else know why is doesn't want to connect to my Database

Comment: I prefer not using OLE provider, `SQLNCLI10` in VBA because if i am not worng, it has to be installed separately. Have you tried using [sqloledb](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/)?

Comment: Use the UDL file method to generate a valid connection string and confirm which drivers you have installed https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-perform-udl-test-check-sql-server-connectivity

Answer (score 1):

Try using "SQLOLEDB" or "SQLNCLI11" in your SQLConStr String instead of "SQLNCLI10"